# Prolog exercise with structures and list, strange output

Tags: prolog

It's my first time with prolog so I hope you could help me find out what I'm missing here.

For the command:

```
eq_multiply(equation([variable("a", 2), variable("b", 1)]), 3, MultipliedEquation).
```

I get this output:

```
MultipliedEquation = equation(_2922).
```

Instead, I need to get this output:

```
MultipliedEquation = equation([variable(a, 6.0), variable(b, 3.0)]).
```

That's my code:

```
eq_multiply(equation([]), Factor, Return).
eq_multiply(equation([variable(A, X)|Tail1]), Factor, equation(List)) :-
Res is X * Factor, eq_multiply(equation(Tail1), Factor, equation([variable(A, Res)|List])).
```

Hope you could help me find my mistake, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the argument of the `equation/1` term is always a list (as in your example), you can start by unwrapping the argument:

```
eq_multiply(equation(List), Factor, equation(Result)) :-
    eq_multiply_list(List, Factor, Result).
```

The `eq_multiply_list/3` auxiliary predicate now simply needs to walk the list and perform the multiply operation on each list element. The base case would be when the list is empty:

```
eq_multiply_list([], _, []).
```

If the list if not empty, you process the head of the list and then process the tail of the list:

```
eq_multiply_list([variable(A, X)| Tail1], Factor, [variable(A, Res)| Tail2]) :-
    Res is X * Factor,
    eq_multiply_list(Tail1, Factor, Tail2).
```

Your sample query:

```
?- eq_multiply(equation([variable("a", 2), variable("b", 1)]), 3, MultipliedEquation).
MultipliedEquation = equation([variable("a", 6), variable("b", 3)]).
```

Comment: @Teddy the OP is very confused. Look at the edit history of the question.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks.